# Box shadow in IE7 and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, css

I want to implement box shadows in IE7 and IE8.
I have tried everything without succeeding. Here is the css that I am using to apply colored shadow to a div:

```
.bright{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -3px 55px 20px #147197;
    box-shadow: 0px -3px 55px 20px #147197;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -3px 55px 20px #147197;
    behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);
}
```

This ie-css3.htc file is a solution to IE shadow problems. But it only gives black shadows, not colour shadows. I tried:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#969696', Direction=100, Strength=13);
```

But it creates a directional shadow, and I want an omni-directional shadow. Also tried blur filter but it needs to have additional divs which is unadvisable in my current case. Any expert opinion on this problem ?

Comment: which version of IE do you want the shadow in? IE7? IE8? IE6? IE5.5?

Comment: **box-shadow is supported in IE9**, and not needed in IE8 and older. Stop using dumb hacks, as they only make user experience even worse for poor users of those old browsers.

Comment: i want that in IE7 IE8. IE 9 is supporting that i know

Comment: @c69 [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) works great in older versions of IE and definitely enhances the UX.

Comment: @nickb buy an old pc (or make a virtual one, but with specs matching 2005-2007 year)  and check how fast will IE run there. After that - reconsider "enhanced UI" argument.

Comment: @c69 Runs fine. Try running [the Vista/IE7 VM straight from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575) with minimal specs and try it yourself.

Comment: @c69 - if you work in a corporate environment, you don't get the luxury to just decide what you will and will not deliver.  If the requirement comes down that you have to have drop shadows in IE7, then as the developer, you figure out how to do that.  I couldn't imagine going back to the client and saying "sorry, I know you want that, but I decided that your users don't need it so I didn't do it".

Comment: _offtopic: @ColoradoRockie there are plenty of jobs for web-developers, and corporate does not always mean "my boss is an idiot". Your role as a specialist is to do what is best for your client, and when he is insisting on shooting him in the foot - your obligation is to at least inform him about all the unfortunate consequences._

Comment: @c69 - nor does it mean that my boss is an idiot.  It means that according to 3 different analytics tools, IE8, then IE7 are the 2 most popular browsers used by their visitors.  So we try to make it look the best we can in those browsers.
Again, think old brick & mortar businesses, banker types, not guys with black rimmed glasses and messenger bags.

Comment: @ColoradoRockie or you could just not say it that way?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/), which emulates [some CSS3 properties](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/) in older versions of IE.

It supports `box-shadow` ([except for](https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues/3) the `inset` keyword).

Comment: If you absolutely need an inset boxshadow for Internet Explorer 5.5 through 8, please look at my advanced method with CSS-only (no javascript) complete code example below.

Answer (score 5):

in ie8 you can try

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135, Color='#c0c0c0')";
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=5, Direction=135, Color='#c0c0c0');
```

caveat: in ie8 you loose smooth fonts for some reason, they will look ragged

Comment: I am using a custom font from google-fonts and I don't see the loss of font-smoothing you mention. Also, I only needed the `filter:` not the `-ms-filter`.

Comment: Is there any way to make the shadow go to 3 sides, say left, right and bottom, instead of just two?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this

```
box-shadow:
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=10, Color='#19000000'), 
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=10, OffY=20, Color='#19000000'), 
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=20, OffY=30, Color='#19000000'), 
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=30, OffY=40, Color='#19000000');
```

Answer (score 0):

use this for fixing issue with shadow box

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow (OffX='2', OffY='2', Color='#F13434', Positive='true');
```