# Custom image border in CSS

Tags: css

So i want to make a text field that look like this:

[image]

which can resize as the text is shorter or longer in some way like this

ex; [image] and [image]

Here are the parts i got [image] , [image] , [image]

So is there any easy way to make that with css?

Comment: Why not simply use CSS `border` and `background-color` (and possibly `box-shadow` and `border-radius`) and save the worry of `background-image`-jigsaw?

Comment: If i use box-shadow it wont work in internet explorer, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181699/box-shadow-in-ie7-and-ie8

Comment: I don't think box shadow works on `input` elements @DavidThomas, am I mistaken?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/drwyf/) (though only tested in Chromium 22/Ubuntu 12.10).

Comment: @DavidThomas: I think I'm mistaken then, not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: Use 3 DIVs ( left,center,right) , set center DIV to repeat-x and put a transparent input in the center DIV.

Answer (score 0):

EXAMPLE

```
<style>


.class_name{border: 1px solid white;-moz-border-radius:19px;
-webkit-border-radius: 19px;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #666;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #666;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #666;
padding:2px 10px;
text-align:center;
width:70px; height:auto;
margin:0px auto;}
</style>
```

html code

```
<div class="class_name">sample</div>
```

Comment: I think the OP's trying to make an input, something the user can type into.