# Add a text shadow when scrolled (jquery or javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have this html and css code:

```
<div class="header">

</div>

.header {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#3b5998;
    height:95px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
position:fixed;
}
```

What i'm trying to do here is the header should be in the fixed position (top) whenever the user scrolls down. I have no problem with that. I easily accomplished that task.

I want to add a different styling on it when the user scrolls down. I want to add a box shadow effect on it when the user scrolls down so it will look elevated. If the user scrolls up and reached the top portion of my webpage, it will revert back to the default css style (which has no box shadow).

More like saying:

scrolled down = activate box shadow effect

if  scrolled up and reached the top = revert back

I am not aware of any css code for this, maybe someone will help me with their javascript/jquery expertise to make a code?

sorry if my explanation is too long or a little confusing. Thank you very much!

Comment: use $(window).scroll(function(){Your code});

Comment: Do you want to change the shadow based on a firmly defined distance or the current scrolloffset?

Comment: to have a clear example, you can look at this website: http://www.bendaggers.com/ his header is fixed at the top. what i'm trying to accomplish here is the same BUT i want to have a dark box shadow at the bottom of the header whenever the user scrolls down the page. also note that if the the user goes up and reached the top, the dark box shadow of the border will disappear.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14755322/1250044

Comment: Whatever solution you use, I wouldn't recommend using `.css()`...declare a class in CSS and use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`. If you must manually configure the shadow very often and specifically (like changing the effect of `box-shadow` for every scroll), then you might need to use `.css()`. If it's more of a "it's only on or off" thing, then stick with classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
if (document.body.scrollTop === 0)
     $(".header").css({"box-shadow":"none"});
else
     $(".header").css({"box-shadow":"0px 0px 1px #EEE"});
});
```

[See Demo For Reference only](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/xBjFL/3/)

Comment: why -1 Please tell reason?

Comment: $(window).scroll(function(){
if (document.body.scrollTop === 0)
 box-shadow:none;
else
 box-shadow:0px 0px 1px #EEE;
});


is it correct?

Comment: @KareenLagasca Its based on your requirement. See updated answer

Comment: @KareenLagasca See demo for your reference

Comment: will try your code when i get home, my office computer really sucks. IT dept only installed IE8 so the box shadow effect is not visible. but I hope your code will work. been stuck for on this part for a day. btw, jsfiddle is not working also because IT dept blocked it. i dunno why, maybe cause they caught my workers playing js games online. lol thanks by the way, i will get back to you later this day. thank you very much! :)

Comment: @KareenLagasca Try to google for that IE8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181699/box-shadow-in-ie7-and-ie8

Comment: hi dineshkani, i like your work? i'm trying to add a little bit of transition but i can do it. I thinking adding a smooth fade in effect? is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var win = $(window),
    doc = $(document),
    header = $('.header');

win.scroll(function(e) {
    var scrollPercent = win.scrollTop() / (doc.height() - win.height()),
        scrollPercentRounded = (scrollPercent * 100).toFixed(2);

    header.css({boxShadow: '0 0 ' + scrollPercentRounded + 'px #000'});
});
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xBjFL/2)**

Comment: will try your code when i get home, my office computer really sucks. IT dept only installed IE8 so the box shadow effect is not visible. but I hope your code will work. been stuck for on this part for a day.

btw, jsfiddle is not working also because IT dept blocked it. i dunno why, maybe cause they caught my workers playing js games online. lol thanks by the way, i will get back to you later this day. thank you very much! :)

Comment: @KareenLagasca I would appreciate about your feedback :-)

Comment: hey, yckart. I tried your code and it really work. Maybe you can modify it a little bit for me? the problem with your code is the box shadow starts from zero (nothing) then it will increase. can you make it from "Border:none;" to (let's say) "border: 0px 5px 5px #000;" ?

Answer (score -2):

With [this code](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xBjFL/9/) you get a nice smooth transition:

```
var $doc = $(document),
    $target = $('.header'),
    limit = 200,
    shadowStyle = '0 2px 5px',
    rgb = '0,0,0';

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var top = $doc.scrollTop();

    if (top <= limit) {
        var opac = 1/limit*top;
        $target.css('box-shadow', shadowStyle+' rgba('+rgb+','+opac+')');
    }
});
```

You can easily modify the shadow styles and `limit` to define on which range it should fade in/out.