# Set CSS Border Color for edges

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to set the 'important' color of the border:

I want to top-border to be displayed over the left-border.

Here's a code snippet:

```css
.border {
        border-top: 4px solid #ccc;
        border-left: 4px solid #06f;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="border">
        test
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you just want a top border and a left border?

Comment: Are you saying you want the corners to reflect the top color?

Comment: If so, anything is possible if you throw enough code at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I can see how to do it is to alter the HTML:

```css
.border {
  border-top: 4px solid #ccc;
}

.border2 {
  border-left: 4px solid #06f;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div class="border2">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

No, because the borders do not overlap, but form a 45 degree angle, you can see it better in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WhyB8/1/)

```
.border {
    border-top: 50px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 50px solid #06f;
}
```

Comment: You can do it, you just can't do it with that HTML.

Comment: Well, yes, you can "mimic" the border behavior with surrounding elements, this way you can do it even JS free, but it's not exactly what he asked. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

you need **border** and **box-shadow** for that

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2grdg/1/)

```
.border {
    box-shadow:0 -4px 0 0 #ccc;
    border-left: 4px solid #06f;
}
```

the markup

```
<div class="border">test</div>
```

Comment: good answer, box-shadow isn't well supported by (guess who) IE [see here](http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow). Only **IE9+**

Comment: Use CSS3 PIE for old browsers also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181699/box-shadow-in-ie7-and-ie8

Answer (score 2):

EDIT : it seems like Liam posted something similar while I was working on my fiddle ;)

put the border-left on a span or a p inside of the div like this

```
<div class="border">
  <span>test</span>
</div>
```

with the CSS :

```
.border {border-top: 4px solid #ccc;}
.border span{border-left: 4px solid #06f;}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WhyB8/3/)

Comment: think we answered at the same time so 50-50 :)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the inner content in another `div`.

HTML :

```
<div class="greyBorder">
    <div class="blueBorder">test</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.greyBorder {
    border-top: 4px solid #ccc;
}

.blueBorder {
    border-left: 4px solid #06f;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LuKaq/)