# How to add a second border around a CSS circle

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS which creates a red circle (JS fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/47BDT/)

```
<div class="shadow-circle"></div>

.shadow-circle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 6px solid red;
    -moz-background-clip: content;     /* Firefox 3.6 */
    -webkit-background-clip: content;  /* Safari 4? Chrome 6? */
    background-clip: content-box;      /* Firefox 4, Safari 5, Opera 10, IE 9 */
}
```

I want to add a 1px blue border around the circle (also a circular border). How do I do this? Solution needs to work in IE8.

Comment: Solution won’t work in IE8, since border-radius doesn’t work in IE8.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a `box-shadow` to add a secondary border around the circle. Aside from that, the `border-radius` won't even work in IE8, as it [**isn't supported**](http://caniuse.com/border-radius). You would need a polyfill if you want to gain support across old, outdated browsers.

[**jsFidle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/7aD66/)

**CSS**

```
.shadow-circle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border: 6px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Also, `box-shadow` [**isn't supported by IE8 either**](http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow).

Comment: or [multiple borders](http://jsfiddle.net/7aD66/1/) if you're feeling particularly psychedelic ;)

Answer (score 5):

I think JoshC’s way is probably best, but another way is to use a pseudo-element:

```
.shadow-circle:after {
  content: ' ';
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid blue;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
}
```

Here’s [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/47BDT/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a `box-shadow`. Leave the blur at `0` (third part of the property) while setting the *spread* to `1px`.

```css
.shadow-circle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 6px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see this post [Box shadow in IE7 and IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181699/box-shadow-in-ie7-and-ie8)

You can find this response, which you can find useful:

> Use CSS3 PIE, which emulates some CSS3 properties in older versions of
>   IE.
>
> It supports box-shadow (except for the inset keyword).