# fallback border for image with shadow in ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, border, shadow

so i have a nice box-shadow that seems to work in all browsers except ie 8 and below. I need my site to be compatible for IE 8.

here is the effect that i'm referring to:
http://unifiedforuganda.com/ugandanprograms.html

here is the relevant css:

```
    .program-image {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 400px;
        padding: 2px;
        margin: 10px 20px 10px 0;
        -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px 3px #414141;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px 3px #414141;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px 3px #414141;
    }
```

i don't care about the shadow showing up in IE but is it possible to have a black border be there for the image only when the shadow is not rendered? i want to avoid IE conditional sheets if possible

EDIT: seems i even have to use conditional comments or use a hack which i don't want to. now just have to figure out to use the conditional comments for IE....

Comment: How do you expect it change conditionally if you avoid conditional CSS?

Comment: that is the reason i am asking. just like when the -webkit-text-fill-color property overrides the color property in safari/chrome. so i'm asking if there is something equivalent for ie and borderds

Comment: Yep there is, it is conditional statements!

Comment: `-webkit-text-fill-color` is conditional CSS, sort of. It only has an effect on Webkit browsers. In order for this to work how you want it to, you'll want to use some conditional CSS. Adding `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` isn't really all that bad. It's unfortunate that we still have to accommodate older browsers, but IE8 is still out in the wild and having to design sites for corporate users whose budget doesn't allow them to upgrade from their XP boxes, I feel your pain...

Comment: alright, i surrender. can someone help me with conditional statement for IE 8 and below (because shadow is supported in IE 9 and above correct?). i have never written conditional css, and i only need it for this one page so i don't want to create a whole new css sheet, just insert it into my existing one....

Comment: Time to upgrade IE if you expect something beautiful

Comment: Not everyone can upgrade. There's always Modernizr if you want to avoid conditional commented stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow), `box-shadow` is not supported until IE9. But [here is a SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181699/box-shadow-in-ie7-and-ie8) expalining the usability of box-shadow in IE8 and below.

Comment: thanks for the link, i saw that earlier in doing my research before asking and it seemed to be a bit of a "hack". is that officially supported or maybe i don't really understand how it works

Comment: Pretty much anything that make IE8 and lower act as a "normal" browser is some kind of hack, that doesn't mean it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

so i ended up using conditional comments in the  of the html document...simplier than i thought....here the code i ended up using:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
     <style type="text/css">
         .program-image { border: 1px solid black; }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

this will target the .program-image class that normally has the box shadow working in most other browsers but when that fails, the above code will kick in and apply a small black border...this is the css:

```
.program-image {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 400px;
padding: 2px;
margin: 10px 20px 10px 0;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px 3px #414141;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px 3px #414141;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 15px 3px #414141;
}
```