# box-shadow is not working in ie-8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html5-canvas

Hi in my code box shadow is *not working properly for i-e 8*
here is my css

```
.lt-ie9 .imageonHover:hover  {
    box-shadow:1px 1px 5px 5px #E7E0E7;
    border-radius:3px;
    zoom: 1;
      filter:
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=0,strength=1),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=45,strength=1),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=90,strength=2),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=135,strength=3),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=180,strength=10),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=225,strength=3),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=270,strength=2),
          progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,direction=315,strength=1);
}

.imageonHover:hover {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 5px 5px #E7E0E7;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px 5px #E7E0E7;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 5px 5px #E7E0E7; 
  }
```

When i hover on div , the text is also showing shadow.On other browsers it is working fine but on ie 8 it is not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Box shadow in IE7 and IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181699/box-shadow-in-ie7-and-ie8)

Comment: You might want to use [CSS PIE](http://css3pie.com/) to enable css3 stuff in IE6-9

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/), which emulates [some CSS3 properties](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/) in older versions of IE.

It supports box-shadow ([except](https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues/3) for the inset keyword).